# How use Vuesax upload component in Laravel/Vue.js project?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm working on this project base on tutorials around web and YOUTUBE .
My problem is that base on tutorial I've got a from like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mellicode_front_url" class="col-sm-2 control-label">scan</label>

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="file" @change="updateMelliCodeFrontScan" name="mellicode_front_url" class="form-input" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-12">
            <button @click.prevent="saveMelliCodeFrontScan" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">submit scan</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

as u can see in this code when i opened a IMAGE file i use `@change` method, then I'll use `click.prevent` in submit button to upload image into host.

problem is I'm using component from this site :

https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/components/upload.html

which it's using this type of code for uploading :

```
<vs-upload action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" @on-success="successUpload" />
```

I've changed and removed action with `onChange` and other things but just because i'm beginner i'm sure i didn't properly. so what i'm trying to do is implement those `@change="updateShenasnameScan"` & `@click.prevent="saveShenasnameScan"` into this `vs-upload` component.

Answer (score 0):

I think that component not supporting the binding or form object to assign the files to it.
But in the backend in Laravel you can get files by **$_FILES**, this will gives you an object of files that you can use it and store the files simply on the server.

Here is my work on this upload system

> Laravel Function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $stored = [];
    $files = $_FILES;
    foreach ($files['archive']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {
        $file = file_get_contents($value);
        if(Storage::disk('local')->put('archive/'. $files['archive']['name'][$key], $file)){
            $stored[$key] = 'archive/'. $files['archive']['name'][$key];
        }else{
            $stored[$key] = $files['archive']['error'][$key];
        }
    }
    return $stored;
}
```

> And the VUE code, that you can find more about it here https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/components/upload.html#automatic

```
<vs-upload multiple fileName='archive[]' automatic action="/api/archive" @on-success="successUpload" />
```

> And the **$_FILES** data as bellow

[image]

Comment: its late, but may help someone :)